# Android JSON array count

Tags: android, arrays, json

So as I'm digging deeper in to Android, I've come to JSON and loading in to RecyclerView. Now, it works fine with the exception of how many it will load being forced. Currently I am loading 40 items which is what is on my website. Now If I go and create a new post on the website, I get an error on my app because it doesnt match how many I have declared in my FOR loop.

My question is, how do I go about making the loop not forced to a specific number of results and just grab them all?

```
private void parsejson(String response) {

        List<DataMembers> data = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
            for(int i=0;i<40;++i) {
                DataMembers dataMembers = new DataMembers();

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                Log.i("Imported: ", Integer.toString(jsonObject.getInt("id")));

                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
                    JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();
                    JSONObject jsonObject3 = new JSONObject();
                    JSONObject jsonObject4 = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("title");
                    jsonObject3 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("excerpt");
                    jsonObject4 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("better_featured_image");
                    jsonObject2 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("content");
                    dataMembers.postTitle = jsonObject1.getString("rendered");
                    dataMembers.postCode = jsonObject2.getString("rendered");
                    dataMembers.postExcerpt = jsonObject3.getString("rendered");
                    dataMembers.imgurl = jsonObject4.getString("source_url");
                    dataMembers.postId = jsonObject.getInt("id");

                    temp[i] = dataMembers.postCode;
                    dataMembers.posturl = jsonObject.getString("link");

                    data.add(dataMembers);
            }
            rview.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter(RestActivity.this,data));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't hardcore the number of array items as 40, instead figure it out from the JSONArray available apis (length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your code should be

```
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); ++i) {
        DataMembers dataMembers = new DataMembers();

        JSONObject members = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.i("Imported: ", Integer.toString(members.getInt("id")));

        JSONObject title = members.getJSONObject("title");
        JSONObject exercpt = members.getJSONObject("excerpt");
        JSONObject image = members.getJSONObject("better_featured_image");
        JSONObject content = members.getJSONObject("content");

        dataMembers.postTitle = title.getString("rendered");
        dataMembers.postCode = content.getString("rendered");
        dataMembers.postExcerpt = exercpt.getString("rendered");
        dataMembers.imgurl = image.getString("source_url");
        dataMembers.postId = members.getInt("id");

        temp[i] = dataMembers.postCode;
        dataMembers.posturl = members.getString("link");

        data.add(dataMembers);
    }
    rview.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter(RestActivity.this,data));
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Use the length of the `JSONArray` instead of a hardcoded number. Also do not do things like

```
JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
jsonObject1 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("title");
```

It creates a completely unnecessary object with `new JSONObject()` then throws it away. Also stop using `get` and casting to `JSONObject` afterwards. Instead declare the variable when you want to actually assign it's value and use `getJSONObject`. Also, give your variables meaningful names.

```
JSONObject title = members.getJSONObject("title");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use JsonArray.length()

The JsonArray.length() gives the size or count of the JsonArray.

```
int length = jsonArray.length();
```

---

```
private void parsejson(String response) {

    List<DataMembers> data = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

        for(int i=0;i< jsonArray.length();++i) 
        {
            DataMembers dataMembers = new DataMembers();
            // The rest of the code goes here
         } // End for
        }  // End Try
     }    // End method parsejson
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

I think Jdk 8 can help... plus some syntactic sugar.

Iterate through the JSONArray, passing in a function for each object... This way, you need no count/length.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
try {
    jsonArray.forEach(obj -> {                               //looping through the Array
        //All other things goes here... 
        });   
    } catch (JSONException j) {
        log.e("JSON 'PUFF' EXCEPTION", j.getMessage());
      }
```